# get "_id" from [ ] in v-for loop and reuse it in data // vuecli

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-cli

i'm looping in [postArray] to get some posts, each post have it's own "_id". And I want to reuse this "_id" to add likes to the correct post.

this is the v-for loop:

```
<div class="posts" v-for="(element, index) in postArray" :key="index">
    <p>{{ element.title }}</p>
    <p>{{ element.content }}</p>
    <p>{{ element.likes.length }}</p>
    <button @click="addLike">Add Like</button>
  </div>
```

this is the data were i want to store my the id in postId:

```
data() {
return {
  title: "",
  content: "",
  postArray: [],
  postId: "",
};
```

},

and this is the methods were i want to reuse the _id:

```
async addLike() {
  const url =
    "https://dw-s3-nice-master-cake.osc-fr1.scalingo.io/post/like";

  const options = {
    method: "POST",

    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      Authorization: "bearer " + localStorage.getItem("token"),
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      postId: this.postId,
    }),
  };
  const response = await fetch(url, options);
  const data = await response.json();
  console.log(data);
  this.postId = data.posts._id;
  console.log(this.postId);
},
```

also the screen of the console.log(data):

[console.log screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0hxPY.png)

[enter image description here][2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to send _id to your method:

```
<button @click="addLike(element._id)">Add Like</button>
```

and then receive it:

```
async addLike(id) {
  ...
  postId: id,
  ...
```